# Getting Spring Security KeyCloak Adapter and Spring Security ACL to play together

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a grails 4 application that uses Spring Security ACL to protect access to resources. I am trying to incorporate KeyCloak SSO into the mix and unable to figure out how to bridge the two worlds. I've configured KeyCloak Authentication and after login can see keyCloakPrincipal on SpringSecurity Context. How do I go from here to set up the roles for ACL?

**here is my keycloak adapter:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
      AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
 
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
         = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
          new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
 
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
 
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
          new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/customers*")
          .hasRole("user")
          .anyRequest()
          .permitAll();
    }
}
```

**and here is my ACL:**

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
 
@Bean
public AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
    return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(
      new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
}
 
@Bean
public PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy() {
    return new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(
      new ConsoleAuditLogger());
}
 
@Bean
public EhCacheBasedAclCache aclCache() {
    return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(
      aclEhCacheFactoryBean().getObject(), 
      permissionGrantingStrategy(), 
      aclAuthorizationStrategy()
    );
}
 
@Bean
public EhCacheFactoryBean aclEhCacheFactoryBean() {
    EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactoryBean = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
    ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheManager(aclCacheManager().getObject());
    ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheName("aclCache");
    return ehCacheFactoryBean;
}
 
@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean aclCacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
}
 
@Bean 
public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() { 
    return new BasicLookupStrategy(
      dataSource, 
      aclCache(), 
      aclAuthorizationStrategy(), 
      new ConsoleAuditLogger()
    ); 
}


How do I
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem?

Comment: Yes, those two don't play together well, better not to use them in the same app. Or if you have no choice, get your hands dirty attach the source code, and get ready to start hacking away. Took me an ungodly amount of time. I had to do this for my last employer, don't remember the details now, and don't have access to the code.